# Quick seek on ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to implement a scrubber for ExoPlayer, to show a thumbnail preview of the position the user is seeking to. While my current implementation is working, the thumbnail only refreshes after the user has stopped dragging the seekbar view, or paused for an instant. It appears as if the seek command on ExoPlayer is implementing something like a debounce function, to prevent too many seeks in succession.

While I can work around this by doing my own throttling on the seekbar callback and send a seek request every x milliseconds, I would like to know if there is a way to tell ExoPlayer to not drop seek requests so the thumbnail can update in real time.

For reference, this is my current implementation:

Subject for throttling:

```
private final Subject<Long> subject = PublishSubject.create();
```

Observer for seek requests with throttling:

```
subject
        .throttleLast(400L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(position -> exoPlayer.seekTo(position));
```

Seekbar callback:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(@NonNull final SeekBar seekBar,
                              final int progress,
                              final boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        final long position = computePosition(progress);
        subject.onNext(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell how did you achieve preview on drag?

Comment: Any updates on this ? Have the same frustrating issue

Answer (score 11):

This is old, but might be useful for someone:

As of **2.7.0** ExoPlayer has the method `Player.setSeekParameters()`
If you want to snap the seek position to the closest keyframe use `SeekParameters.CLOSEST_SYNC` (faster but less accurate). To see to a exact frame (the frame before the requested position, even if it's not a keyframe) use `SeekParameters.EXACT`.

Comment: Useful. Thank you.

Comment: definitely made it faster, although, having a hard time making the black frames disappear

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is the optimal solution, but you can look at this open source project which achieves roughly something you're looking for. [Here is the Github](https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar).

It looks like they use a [custom LoadControl](https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/rubensousa/previewseekbar/sample/exoplayer/PreviewLoadControl.java) to get ExoPlayer to render frames quicker. And I believe they're compounding that with selection of the worst quality so it loads even faster.

This is the code they use in that library's `onProgressChange(...)`:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if(fromUser){
        int offset = (float) progress / seekBar.getMax()
        // Round the offset before seeking. The sample uses 1% or 10% of the video per each thumbnail
        previewPlayer.seekTo((long) (offset * previewPlayer.getDuration()));
        previewPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

---

Another way to do this is to actually grab a thumbnail off of the `TextureView` - which they cover in [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1670). The caveat being there are some limitations to using multiple renderers.

Comment: Thanks for those pointers. The seekbar itself will not help as the issue is within ExoPlayer itself, but it may well be that the custom load control helps here, I'll investigate that approach.

Comment: Cool, let me know how you make out, @Francesc.

Comment: Using a custom load control that instructs the player to start playback sooner (after only 50ms worth of video has been buffered) did not help. It still appears to be an issue with the player debouncing seek requests, looks like I'll have to dig into the player code to figure out how it handles multiple seek requests in quick succession.

Comment: Any updates on this ? Have the same frustrating issue